# Need some explanation about getting max in XPath

Tags: xpath, max

I'm kinda new to XPath and I've found that to get the max attribute number I can use the next statement: `//Book[not(@id > //Book/@id)` and it works quite well.

I just can't understand why does it return max id instead of min id, because it looks like I'm checking whether id of a node greater than any other nodes ids and then return a Book where it's not.

I'm probably stupid, but, please, someone, explain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not querying for maximum values, but for minimum values. Your query

```
//Book[not(@id > //Book/@id)
```

could be translated to natural language as "Find all books, which do not have an `@id` that is larger than any other book's `@id`". You probably want to use

```
//Book[not(@id < //Book/@id)
```

For arbitrary input you might have wanted to use `<=` instead, so it only returns a single maximum value (or none if it is shared). As `@id`s must be unique, this does not matter here.

Be aware that `//Book[@id > //Book/@id]` is not equal to the query above, although math would suggest so. XPath's comparison operators adhere to a kind of set-semantics: if any value on the left side is larger than any value on the right side, the predicate would be true; thus it would include all books but the one with minimum `@id` value.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the explanation I was looking for.

The only thing I didn't understand is why `<=` would return a single maximum?

And in your last example I think you meant '_if any value on the left side is **greater** than any value on the right side_', since you have a greater than operator.

Comment: `<=` only returns single maximums. If There would be two books with the same (maximal) id, none would be returned as there is another book with the same id. You're right about the last sentence, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides XPath 1.0 your function is correct, in XPath 2.0:

```
/Books/Book[id = max(../Book/id)]
```

The `math:max` function returns the maximum value of the nodes passed as the argument. The maximum value is defined as follows. The node set passed as an argument is sorted in descending order as it would be by `xsl:sort` with a data type of number. The maximum is the result of converting the string value of the first node in this sorted list to a number using the number function.

If the node set is empty, or if the result of converting the string values of any of the nodes to a number is NaN, then NaN is returned.

The math:max template returns a result tree fragment whose string value is the result of turning the number returned by the function into a string.

Comment: Thanks for this function, but I would still want to understand why my version returns max instead of min.